# React Native - Linked NativeModule works when run from Xcode, but not from packager

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bugsnag

I recently added [bugsnag-react-native](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/) and followed the directions for linking. When I run using the packager without Xcode, I get the following error screen.

[image]

When I search on Google for answers, the only relevant issue posted is [Runtime Error: No Native client found](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/issues/14) which suggests that its a linking problem and to follow the directions, but from my perspective everything looks fine and I followed the direction.

What reason would a native module only be available when run from Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and below solved it:

If you can successfully run from Xcode, then delete your `ios/build` folder (`rm -rf ios/build`) and re-run `react-native run-ios`.